# Ethernet Media-Independent Interface Management Control results in "link down"

Tags: vhdl, fpga, ethernet

I am working on an Ethernet driver for the Digilent Nexys4 board (Artix7 FPGA). I have written a VHDL component to communicate with the LAN8720A PHY in MDIO protocol. It works well, When I send a frame asking to write in a register, I can read the value I wrote. But when I ask to read the Basic Status Register, it returns a link down status.

That means the Ethernet link is down and I cannot send Ethernet frames. I have absolutely no idea of why I have the link down status. Even when I let the auto-negociation enabled, after the auto-negiacion is over when I try to send a frame, I have a link down status.

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening and maybe how I can fix this ?

Thanks.

EDIT : it seems it is because of the DATA_VALID signal of the LAN8720A. Does anyone know how can I set the signal to '1' ?

EDIT2 : for more precisions, DATA_VALID is an internal signal of the LAN8720A. It is used to pull up or down the link state bit of the status register.

Comment: What's on the other side? Does it not establish a link with a known working device like a PC?

Comment: It is a PC on the other side. When the PHY is doing auto-negociation, I can ping the board with the PC but nothing comes out of the board.

Comment: When connected to a PC, what's the value of the status register? And are you sure the clocking is correct accoring to chapter 4 of https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/nexys:nexys4:nexys4_rm.pdf

Comment: When connected to a PC, the status register has a value of 782Dh. The link state bit is up. I verified my clocking multiple times, I saw no problem in it. I will verify it again. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: 0x782D would indicate autonegotiation is done (bit 5) and the link is up (bit2) . You should see CRS_DV go high when a packet is incoming from the PC.

Comment: I can receive and analyze a packet from the PC. This is not the problem. The problem is that I cannot send anything from the board. The DATA_VALID signal is internal to the PHY it is not CRS_DV. DATA_VALID indicates that it receives valid data and if not, the link state bit is put down.

Comment: If I read the data sheet correctly the DATA_VALID is only related to the RXP and RXN and should not be influenced by your transmission, it is just an indication of the link pulses (for base10) or the idle characters on the line (for base100).

Does the link stay up until you try to send?

Comment: Yes, it should not be influenced, but I don't see any other cause for my problem. The link stays up until I try to send. Whenever I try to send, it goes down for 1.5 seconds then goes up. A colleague said it resembles a reset.

Comment: Does the  PHY Special Control/Status Register (31) indicate that the link is 100base-TX full duplex? If it's running on half-duplex you might be causing a collision.

Comment: The PHY Special Control/Status Register indicates 1058h, that means 100base-TX full duplex, auto-negociation complete.

Comment: I assume you already double checked the pinning for the reset and tx pins. 

Does the problem still exist after a hardware reset of the PHY without powering down?

Comment: Yes, I doubled checked the pinning for the PHY, and the problems still persists after reset of the PHY (hardware or software). I even tried to use the Mode pins to set the PHY as I wanted, it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a demo/reference project with which you can confirm there's no hardware issue? And can you show, on the chipscope, the TXD, TXEN, nRST, CLKIN to the LAN8720 ?

Comment: I have a reference project which works perfectly (sending and receiving Ethernet frames). I don't think it's a hardware issue, I tried on another board and I have the same problems.
I don't have the equipments needed to see directly the signals on the hardware. I only have a PC and a Nexys4 board.
I just implemented a clocking wizard IP core to be sure of the generated clocks. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Vivado has the option to insert an internal logic analyzer (I think it's called chipscope?) that lets you see individual signals in the logic. You can use it to see the waveforms for the signals you're interested in.

Comment: Oh ! Thanks ! I'll try to use it later. I will tell you the results.

Comment: I used the ILA (Internal Logic Analyzer) core of Vivado to probe the signals you advised me to. The results ? The phy clock is not correct... The clock is not periodic. There are holes in the clock signals and sometimes there are multiple clock tops when there shouldn't have any...
Thank you for your help, I will work on my clocking, in hope it will resolve the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem : I did not respect the interframe time. Now that I respect the interframe time, the link state does not go down, it stays up. Though the frame is still not sent, it is a great step forward.